# Theme from Themeforest. The package could not be installed. The theme is missing the style.css stylesheet

Tags: wordpress, themes, uploading

I purchased a theme  from themeforest and I'm trying to upload it on wordpress.

Below error message appears when I try to upload the theme.

"The package could not be installed. The theme is missing the style.css stylesheet"

This  can be uploaded and edited on shppify.com (https://accounts.shopify.com/store-login) but I prefer to work with wordpress.

I need to upload this theme on wordpress. Please help me and guide me to get this done. Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to install a Shopify theme on WordPress? If so, I don't think that'll work. Check with the author of the theme if it's WP compatible.

Comment: Thank you @cabrerahector  for your response. I am new to web developing and appreciate if you could help me out with this. Shopify charges for their platform and I need a platform where  I can upload the theme for free (I have already paid for the theme, domain and hosting). Please help me to upload and edit  this theme without any additional cost. Please refer below link for the relevant theme which I purchased. (https://themeforest.net/item/furni-multipurpose-sections-furniture-shopify-theme/23483154). Thank you!

Comment: From the description it doesn't seem like the theme you bought is WP compatible. You should ask for a refund and buy another theme (and this time make sure it's a WordPress theme.)